# Implementing a jQuery function that downloads files based on checkboxes checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm currently trying to build a function on a website I'm working on that checks what checkboxes the user has checked, and then downloads said files once the user clicks the 'Submit' button. I would of used vanilla JavaScript, but due to the submit button coming from a webform in Drupal meaning I couldn't add on an onClick in the HTML markup, jQuery is the more efficient option here.

I've built the whole block of code, there is just something going wrong when the if statements check whether the checkboxes are checked, and it seems to skip straight to the final else statement and alert the user that they need to 'Please choose a file to download'.

```
// Manual variables
var classic = jQuery('#edit-submitted-manuals-required-1');
var racing = jQuery('#edit-submitted-manuals-required-2');
var flexer = jQuery('#edit-submitted-manuals-required-3');

// Handbook variables
var classicEng = jQuery('#edit-submitted-handbooks-required-1');
var classicMulti = jQuery('#edit-submitted-handbooks-required-2');
var flexerEng = jQuery('#edit-submitted-handbooks-required-3');
var racerEng = jQuery('#edit-submitted-handbooks-required-4');

// Manual download function
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#edit-submit').click(function() {  
        if (classic.is(':checked')) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
        } else if (racing.is(":checked")) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
        } else if (flexer.is(":checked")) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
        } else {
            alert("Please choose a file to download");
        }
    });
});

// Handbook download function
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#edit-submit').click(function() {  
        if (classicEng.is(':checked')) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
        } else if (classicMulti.is(":checked")) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
        } else if (flexerEng.is(":checked")) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
        } else if (racerEng.is(":checked")) {
            window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
        } else {
            alert("Please choose a file to download");
        }
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(I would provide the link to the website, but I've seen people in the past be marked down for providing live links, as obviously once the error has been resolved that link is of no use to users in the future looking at the question)

Comment: As long as you share relevant code along with it, a link to show the issue is fine. You can provide the link as a comment if you don't want it on the question.

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this, just delegate the event listener to the closest ancestor of the element - that's present in the DOM - to listen for the event using [`eventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: as an aside, you don't technically need jQuery in order to add an event listener outside the markup :-). It does have nicer syntax, but it's not a requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is caused by the Manual and Handbook variables being declared before the page has completed loading. I would recommend declaring them in the same place, but updating them inside the `jQuery(document).ready()`, which you can guarantee the elements have been rendered.

The resulting `jQuery(document).ready(function(){});` would look like this:

```
    // Manual variables
    var classic;
    var racing;
    var flexer;

    // Handbook variables
    var classicEng;
    var classicMulti;
    var flexerEng;
    var racerEng;

    // Handbook download function
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            classic = jQuery('#edit-submitted-manuals-required-1');
            racing = jQuery('#edit-submitted-manuals-required-2');
            flexer = jQuery('#edit-submitted-manuals-required-3');

            // Handbook variables
            classicEng = jQuery('#edit-submitted-handbooks-required-1');
            classicMulti = jQuery('#edit-submitted-handbooks-required-2');
            flexerEng = jQuery('#edit-submitted-handbooks-required-3');
            racerEng = jQuery('#edit-submitted-handbooks-required-4');

        jQuery('#edit-submit').click(function() {  
            if (classicEng.is(':checked')) {
                window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
             } else if (classicMulti.is(":checked")) {
                window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
            } else if (flexerEng.is(":checked")) {
                window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
            } else if (racerEng.is(":checked")) {
                window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
            } else if (classic.is(':checked')) {
                window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');        
            } else if (racing.is(":checked")) {        
                window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
            } else if (flexer.is(":checked")) {
                window.open('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
            }  else {
                alert("Please choose a file to download");
            }
        });
    });
```

The reason we continue to declare outside the `jQuery(document).ready()` but update them inside, is so that they remain global variables. If we had declared them inside the `jQuery(document).ready()` they would be out of scope for any function outside `jQuery(document).ready()`.

**In response to your follow up comments about making it able to download multiple files**, I would recommend making it push the names of the files into an array. Once you have pushed them into the array, you can iterate through them with a for loop and then fire off your calls, one by one.

Once again, if you were using a server-side code, you could add these separate files to one zip file to make it even easier for the user. The jQuery/Javascript would look something like this for the non-server-side solution:

```
        jQuery('#edit-submit').click(function() {
            var myArray = []
            if (classicEng.is(':checked')) {
                myArray.push('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
             }
             if (classicMulti.is(":checked")) {
                myArray.push('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
            } 
             if (flexerEng.is(":checked")) {
                myArray.push('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
            } 
             if (racerEng.is(":checked")) {
                myArray.push('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
            } 
             if (classic.is(':checked')) {
                myArray.push('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');        
            }
             if (racing.is(":checked")) {        
                myArray.push('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
            } 
             if (flexer.is(":checked")) {
                myArray.push('/sites/default/files/manuals/file.pdf');
            }  
             //Find out how many files the user has selected
             var totalFiles = myArray.length;
             //Throw an error if no boxes are checked
             if (totalFiles == 0) {
                alert("Please choose a file to download");
             } else {
                     for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
                           //Open a download window for each URL in the array
                           window.open(myArray[i]);
                     }
             }
            }
        });
    });
```

And now to briefly explain the new code. First, I declared an array called `myArray`. I changed your `if`/`else` statements to just `if` statements, and `push` (add) the URL of every checked box into the array.

Once the function has checked each box and added the URL to the array, I declare another variable called `totalItems` which checks the number of items pushed into the array. If there are no items in the array, I throw the `alert` that was in your `else` statement previously.

If there **are** items in your array, the `for` loop goes through each item separately and opens the download window for each.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Good point, if they are just put inside the (document).ready() they wouldn't be accessible by any other function in the future. They are opening in new tabs now which is great. But, as above, the 'Please choose a file to download' seems to ALWAYS pop up even before the page opens even if they have checked a box? Also, I'd prefer if the file downloaded, and not opened in a new tab. I guess the person who answers these issues first, will get the winning answer!

Comment: Also, would it be possible to have the user choose multiple files to download from the checkboxes or would that be an entire rewrite on the code?

Comment: `window.location.href = "[file location]"` would make it open in the same window, but you won't be able to get the file to seemlessly download without using a server-side technology. PHP or ASP.NET would be my weapons of choice.

Comment: Ah I see, I'll start involving some PHP soon then. Any ideas why the alert box asking the user to choose files to download is coming up before the files open even if a checkbox is checked?

Comment: I've just noticed that you had two `jQuery(document).ready()` both applying actions to the page, but one may be running before the variables have been properly defined. 

I have now corrected my code and consolidated your submit button actions into one if/else statement. Let me know how it goes. :)

Comment: Hi Mark, I'll get back to you in just over an hour as I'm not at the PC right now. Cheers for all the help so far!

Comment: Hi Mark, that works very nicely. I've now just gotta work out how to make it open multiple files if more than one checkbox is clicked... One way I can think of doing it extending the if statements to check whether other checkboxes have been ticked via &&, but it's gonna make a whole lot more bulky code to check for every single situation!

Comment: Hi Ryan, I have added an extra passage of text onto the bottom of my answer. I didn't update the code at the top of my answer because it wasn't in your original question and I didn't want to mislead people. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Also, I forgot that you could let the user seamlessly download 1 file if you used a hidden `iframe` on the page. It wouldn't work for multiple files though. You can use jQuery to set the `src` attribute of the `iframe` to the URL of the file you wish to download.

Comment: Wow, cheers Mark Townsend! That's really cleaned up my extremely long code up. I should've thought about arrays. If only we could get Chrome to stop assuming the multiple links opening were pop-ups/advertisements then it'd be golden. Thanks again for all the help, and explanation on your code!

Answer (score 0):

Problem of scope here :)

Your variable are not declared inside the `jQuery(document).ready(function()`

Try to put it inside, so you will avoid the problem where your checkbox need to be under your js script.

Comment: Cheers! That has definitely helped. I have another issue though... First of all, the 'Please choose a file to download' seems to ALWAYS pop up even before the page opens even if they have checked a box? Also, I'd prefer if the file downloaded, and not opened in a new tab.

Comment: Also, would it be possible to have the user choose multiple files to download from the checkboxes or would that be an entire rewrite on the code?